# vue v-show не работает с переменным fetch

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет! У меня такая проблема 
Я получаю данные через fetch и присваиваю к переменной orkkod 
Через этот orkkod я делаю условия на v-show но v-show не работает

```
<div id="app">
<div v-show="orkkod=='TRK'">
    ТРК
</div>
<div  v-show="orkkod=='ETC'">
    ЕТС
</div>
```

```
 <script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            orkkod: ''
        },

        methods: {
            getSesData() {
                fetch('/Account/GetDataOrgKod')
                    .then(responce => responce.json())
                    .then(json => {
                        this.orkkod = json;
                    })
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getSesData();
        }
    });
</script>
```

а если делать через input и туда писать ЗНАЧЕНИЯ условии то работает

```
 <input type="text" v-model="orkkod"/>
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что в ответе от fetch? Если да, то там возвращается TRK, ETC

Comment: Там только один запись код и все это TRK или ETC

Comment: "===" пробовал, не получатеся

Comment: код рабочий. Смотрите в ответ сервера.

Comment: Вот не могу найти решение, может какие то другие способы есть передачи данных от fetch к v-show?

Comment: Выведите в консоль после строки `this.orkkod = json;`содержимое `json`

Comment: Содержимое json "TRK"

Comment: Код у вас верный, я на 99% уверен, что проблема в json.

Comment: Да проблема была в JSON